# Office Open XML SDK - good Introduction?

Tags: c#, automation, ms-office

I am writing a program which modifies POwerpoint files via Office automation. THis is painfully slow and error prone so I attempting to move some functionality to Office Open XML SDK.
I read the introductory texts from Microsoft, but I am lacking a good understand how this whole format works. I am especially  interested in the boundary between Excel and Powerpoint - I am planning to update charts via Office Open Xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to a downloadable copy of [Open XML Explained](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2007/08/13/1970.aspx).

For updating charts, [this docx4j code](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/pptx4j/java/org/pptx4j/samples/EditEmbeddedCharts.java) may be of interest; it shows you how to do it using docx4j; worst case, you can translate each step to C#/Open XML SDK.